# Optimal emission strength for lightbulb

Tags: light

I am making a cone with a lightbulb in it, and I am not very good at modeling yet, so my "lightbulb" is just a sphere.  I added an emission property to the material, and I made a cone that has a diffuse and translucent property, and the RGB value is 0.74 for all of them.  If I am making a regular lamp, what should I use for the strength of the emission for the lightbulb so I can get regular lighting?  The lamp is supposed to be the key light, and I do not want the cone to be completely white.

Comment: are you using internal or cycles? can you post an image of the scene?

Comment: I am using cycles.

Comment: I also don't know how to upload an image from my computer.

Comment: on blender press ctrl F3 to save the image. then edit your question and you'll see tools on the top to insert the image

Comment: There is really no right answer other that what looks good to you.  The size of the object and the distance will affect the intensity of the light on the surrounding objects. Try different values and see what works\

Comment: if you want to upload your file for others to inspect use: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/